# Algorithm: Build a recommendation for movies you might like

Tags: sql, algorithm

I need help designing an algorithm for recommendations on movies.

Every user in the system grades movies on a score between 1-100.

Tables consist of:

```
Table Movies
ID    Name    Year    Rating    Runtime

Table Con_MoviesToGenres
MovieID    GenreID

Table Con_MovieToUser
MovieID    UserID    Grade
```

I'm trying to build a SELECT query to return 5 most recommended movies for a specific movie.

Bearing in mind, I want to integrate in some way, similar genres, highest grades & movie Rating (so you want be recommended an R rated movie for a PG rated movie, unless it's really recommended in every other aspect). Also, if movie matches more than one genre, it will increase its recommendation ratio.

Bonus: If a user gives a low grade to a movie -> it will lose recommendation ratio.

**Update:**
I meant for one user and one title. Whenever a user enters a "movie page" - he will get recommendations for other movies he might like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are late [**the contest**](http://www.netflixprize.com/index) is over.

But its fun.

You will have to look into some fancy math (oh I love all this)

1. Linear Algebra
2. Statistics
3. Artificial Intelligence
4. Graph Theory

Articles:

5. [Item-based Collaborative Filtering Recommendation Algorithms](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/sarwar01itembased.html) (1424 citations)
6. [TANGENT: A Novel, “Surprise-me”, Recommendation Algorithm](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~zha/CSE8801/CF/p657-onuma.pdf)
7. [What is a Good Recommendation Algorithm? - HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=537371)
8. [Tony Phillips' Take on Math in the Media](http://www.ams.org/mathmedia/archive/01-2009-media.html)
9. [We Recommend a Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/archive/svd.html)
10. [Netflix prize tribute: Recommendation algorithm in Python](http://blog.smellthedata.com/2009/06/netflix-prize-tribute-recommendation.html)
11. [Studying Recommendation Algorithms by Graph Analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.3049&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: This is complicated, I know, but I never said it wasn't. (this line is stolon;)

Answer (score 2):

If User A and User B have seen 10 movies in common, and there is a high positive correlation between their ratings (implying they both have similar opinions about movies), you could then take a movie which User B has given a high rating to and recommend it to User A.

To do something like this, maybe you could precompute an extra table which maps User X and User Y to the number of movies they have seen in common and the Pearson's correlation between their ratings

When a user asks for a recommendation you could use this table to find a highly correlated  user, and then recommend something he has seen and liked which this person hasn't

For situations when a user doesn't have enough common users with anybody else, you could fall back to recommending the highest rated movie overall which the user hasn't seen

Comment: But if both seen the same movies, but user B really disliked them while user A loved them?

Comment: then their correlation would be lower and you might pick somebody else instead of User B, to find a movie for User A

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done on an atomic level: calculate recommendations for one title OR user at a time.

There is no way you can fit all the details in a SQL query. This has to be done is real code.

Comment: I meant for one user and one title. Whenever a user enters a "movie page" - he will get recommendations for other movies he might like.

Comment: Good for you. My answer is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be relevant to SQL, but if you like python, there is some tutorial on this topic in a book called [Collective Intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the NetFlix competition. Found an article about it [here](http://tinycomb.com/2009/09/21/netflix-announces-winners-of-movie-reccomendation-algorithm-contest/). May at least give you some good ideas...